# How to justify text in Quarto?

Tags: html, text, quarto, justify

I would like to justify the text in a `Quarto` document. This means that it should automatically add text between words so that both edges of each line of text are aligned with both margins. In a `word-document` this would be the following highlighted symbol:

[image]

So I was wondering if this method is possible in a `Quarto` document? Here is a reproducible example:

```
---
title: "How to justify text in Quarto"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

Quarto is based on Pandoc and uses its variation of markdown as its underlying document syntax. Pandoc markdown is an extended and slightly revised version of John Gruber's Markdown syntax. 

Markdown is a plain text format that is designed to be easy to write, and, even more importantly, easy to read:
```

Output:

[image]

---

As you can see the text is not justified, because the lines of text are not all at both edges of each line with both margins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since output format is HTML, all you need the CSS property `text-align` set as `justify`.

````
---
title: "How to justify text in Quarto"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.justify {
  text-align: justify !important
}
```

## Quarto

::: {.justify}

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

Quarto is based on Pandoc and uses its variation of markdown as its underlying document syntax. Pandoc markdown is an extended and slightly revised version of John Gruber's Markdown syntax and Markdown is a plain text format.

Markdown is a plain text format that is designed to be easy to write, and, even more importantly, easy to read:

:::
````

---

[image: justified text in Quarto]

---

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer by @shafee if you need to justify all the paragraph html elements, `<p>` without creating classes, like using `:::{.justify} :::` you can use:

````
---
title: "How to justify text in Quarto"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

```{css}
#| echo: false
p {
  text-align: justify
}
```

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

Quarto is based on Pandoc and uses its variation of markdown as its underlying document syntax. Pandoc markdown is an extended and slightly revised version of John Gruber's Markdown syntax and Markdown is a plain text format.

Markdown is a plain text format that is designed to be easy to write, and, even more importantly, easy to read:
````

But if you need to justify specific elements use the answer by @shafee. For more information about `text-align` in `css` checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align and the examples.